# <body> methods (onkeydown, onkeyup...) not rendered on JSF

Tags: java, maven, jsf

I am migrating a non-maven webapp project to maven and i am having some issues.
I have in my page:

```
<h:body onkeydown="desabilitaEnterEnvioForm(event);" onkeyup="trocaComboBoxPesquisa(event);">
...
</h:body>
```

But after rendering the html in the browser all i see is this:

```
<body>...</body>
```

For some reason it took out the body methods... What can cause this strange behavior?

**UPDATE**

I run my app in tomcat 8.

here is my web.xml:

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>br.atualy.gestao.restws</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/login/login.jsf</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>home</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

And here is my faces-config.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config version="2.2"
              xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">

    <navigation-rule>
        <description>Voltar para o login</description>
        <from-view-id>/*</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>Login</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/login/login.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>

</faces-config>
```

**UPDATE 2**

I found that the problem is caused by libraries conflict (i think), because if in my pom.xml i put only these dependencies it works:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1-b04</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

But if i put all my project dependencies it causes the error:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1-b04</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.2.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>5.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.17.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.17.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>1.17.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>br.atualy.util</groupId>
    <artifactId>AtualyUtil</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>br.atualy.temas</groupId>
    <artifactId>home</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.10</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
    <artifactId>axis2-kernel</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
    <artifactId>axis2-adb</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

Maybe some of these dependencies are wrong, but which one?

Comment: How should we know? Without any really releavant informations like your pom file what kind of error message? Which maven version do you use etc.?

Comment: Hail! See my updated message

Comment: You are using different implementations of faces...javax.faces (which should be provided as it defines a api), primefaces which is an implementations of JSF which version (2.2?)..and the given answer is related to myfaces..which is an other implementation of JSF...

Comment: I didn't add myFaces to dependencies list, just mojarra and primefaces.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Body attributes (onkeydown, onkeyup...) not rendered after upgrading to Primefaces 5.1, from 4.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26721555/body-attributes-onkeydown-onkeyup-not-rendered-after-upgrading-to-primefac)

Answer (score 0):

I tried with JSF 2.2, this code snippet :

```
<h:body onload="init();" onclick="init();" ondblclick="init();" onkeydown="init();"
        onkeypress="init();" onkeyup="init();" onmousedown="init();" onmousemove="init();"
        onmouseout="init();" onmouseover="init();" onmouseup="init();" onunload="init();" >
</h:body>
```

Here's the generated HTML :

```
<body onload="init();" onunload="init();"></body>
```

It seems only `onload` and `onunload` events are being rendered on `<h:body>`, even though the documentation says otherwise : https://myfaces.apache.org/core21/myfaces-impl/tagdoc/h_body.html

**EDIT :**

Here's a solution to enable support of these events for your `<h:body>` : [Body attributes (onkeydown, onkeyup...) not rendered after upgrading to Primefaces 5.1, from 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26721555/body-attributes-onkeydown-onkeyup-not-rendered-after-upgrading-to-primefac)

Comment: It's strange because in my old project (without using maven) it worked just fine...