# Body attributes (onkeydown, onkeyup...) not rendered after upgrading to Primefaces 5.1, from 4.0

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have set up a simple maven project with the following dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.2</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1-b04</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.2.Final</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
      <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
      <version>5.1</version>
   </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

And this page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
<h:body onkeydown="alert('You pressed some key!')">
    <h:outputLabel value="Hello, young fellows!"/>
</h:body>
</html>
```

This is the generated html, notice the body tag without methods:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><body><label>Hello, young fellows!</label></body>
</html>
```

I tried to rollback the primefaces version to 4.0 by changing the dependency version in pom.xml, like this:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
   <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
   <version>4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And then it works as expected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><body onkeydown="alert('You pressed some key!')"><label>Hello, young fellows!</label></body>
</html>
```

What is the problem? Is it a bug on PF 5.1 or something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting from 5.0 the `h:body` has a [renderer](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/5.0.x/src/main/resources-maven-jsf/standard-renderers.xml#L10) in PrimeFaces, [`BodyRenderer`](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/5.1.x/src/main/java/org/primefaces/renderkit/BodyRenderer.java).

In the `encodeBegin` of that renderer an array of [attributes](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/5.1.x/src/main/java/org/primefaces/renderkit/BodyRenderer.java#L44) is being passed, [`HTML.BODY_ATTRS`](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/5.1.x/src/main/java/org/primefaces/util/HTML.java#L144).

```
public static final String[] BODY_ATTRS = {
    "dir",
    "lang",
    "style",
    "onload",
    "onunload"
};
```

And as you can see that this array for some reason doesn't cover all the actual attributes of the `h:body` tag, thus some of the attributes are being ignored.

In order to avoid this problem you can simply extend that renderer into a one which accepts all the actual attributes.

```
public class CustomBodyRenderer extends BodyRenderer{

   //our array with all the attributes of h:body tag
   public static final String[] BODY_ATTRS = {
       "dir",
       "lang",
       "onclick",
       "ondblclick",
       "onkeydown",
       "onkeypress",
       "onkeyup",
       "onmousedown",
       "onmousemove",
       "onmouseout",
       "onmouseover",
       "onmouseup",
       "style",
       "title",
       "onload",
       "onunload"
   };

   @Override
   public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) throws IOException {
       ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();
       String clientId = component.getClientId(context);
       writer.startElement("body", component);

       if (shouldWriteId(component)) {
           writer.writeAttribute("id", clientId, "id");
       }

       String styleClass = (String) component.getAttributes().get("styleClass");
       if (styleClass != null && styleClass.length() != 0) {
           writer.writeAttribute("class", styleClass, "styleClass");
       }
       //the only changed line from the original renderer
       renderPassThruAttributes(context, component, BODY_ATTRS);
   }

}
```

Then register it in the **faces-config**

```xml
<render-kit>
    <renderer>
        <component-family>javax.faces.Output</component-family>
        <renderer-type>javax.faces.Body</renderer-type>
        <renderer-class>com.hatemalimam.CustomBodyRenderer</renderer-class>
    </renderer>
</render-kit>
```

This way you would get the expected outcome in a "minimal" changes.

I have submitted an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=7621) on the tracker.

**Update:**
*This has been fixed in PF 5.2.*

Comment: Thank you, this really worked, but for some weird reason i have to wait 20 hours to reward you with bounty. Please remember me tomorrow or else i'm sure i will forget !

Comment: @MateusViccari Don't forget to award bounty!

Comment: The fix was indeed included in 5.2!